# OpenID Connect and IdentityServer4: APIs vs scopes

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/api_resource.html says "An API must have at least one scope."

It seems this restriction is not enforced by IdentityServer4: I have

```cs
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis(IConfiguration config)
{
    return new ApiResource[]
    {
        new ApiResource("orm", "Our ORM"),
    };
}
```

(without scopes here) and my software does work and seems not to produce any errors. Do I understand correctly that here I have an error but IdentityServer4 just does not diagnose the error?

Moreover, I have

```cs
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("XXX".Sha256()) },

    RedirectUris = { ormClientURL + "/signin-oidc" },
    FrontChannelLogoutUri = ormClientURL + "/signout-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { ormClientURL + "/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "orm" }
},
```

and it works despite I have no scope `"orm"` defined.

Why does it indeed work?

How to fix this properly? (Which clients and scopes should I define?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the ApiResource constructor adds a Scope using the name and displayName provided:

```
    public ApiResource(string name, string displayName)
        : this(name, displayName, null)
    {
    }

    public ApiResource(string name, string displayName, IEnumerable<string> claimTypes)
    {
        if (name.IsMissing()) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        Name = name;
        DisplayName = displayName;

        Scopes.Add(new Scope(name, displayName));

        if (!claimTypes.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            foreach (var type in claimTypes)
            {
                UserClaims.Add(type);
            }
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/Storage/src/Models/ApiResource.cs